# C++/Size of a 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector, size, dimensions

How do I find the size of a 2 dimensional vector? So far I have the following code which doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector < vector <int> > v2d;

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            v2d.push_back(vector <int> ());
            v2d[x].push_back(y);
        }
    }

    cout<<v2d[0].size()<<endl;
    cout<<v2d[0][0].size()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To get the size of **v2d**, simply use **v2d.size()**.
For size of each vector inside **v2d**, use **v2d[k].size()**.

Note: for getting the *whole size* of `v2d`, sum up the size of each individual vector, as each vector has its own size.

Answer (score 12):

You had some errors in your code, which I've fixed and commented on below.

```
vector < vector <int> > v2d;

for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    // Move push_back() into the outer loop so it's called once per
    // iteration of the x-loop
    v2d.push_back(vector <int> ());
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        v2d[x].push_back(y);
    }
}

cout<<v2d.size()<<endl; // Remove the [0]
cout<<v2d[0].size()<<endl; // Remove one [0]
```

`v2d.size()` returns the number of vectors in the 2D vector. `v2d[x].size()` returns the number of vectors in "row" `x`. If you know the vector is rectangular (all "rows" are of the same size), you can get the total size with `v2d.size() * v2d[0].size()`. Otherwise you need to loop through the "rows":

```
int size = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < v2d.size(); i++)
    size += v2d[i].size();
```

As a change, you can also use [iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/):

```
int size = 0;
for (vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator it = v2d.begin(); it != v2d.end(); ++it)
    size += it->size();
```

Answer (score 10):

The `vector<vector<int>>` does not have a whole size, because each vector within it has an independent size. You need to sum the size of all contained vectors.

```
int size = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < v2d.size(); i++)
    size += v2d[i].size();
```

Comment: Remember the dreaded space! `vector<vector<int> >`, not `vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: @marcog: How old is your compiler? I'm pretty sure that hasn't been necessary since C++98.

Comment: The reqirement for the space has only been dropped in C++0x. Leaving it out is a compile error using GCC. See http://ideone.com/mGdWb

Answer (score 2):

```
int size_row = v2d.size();
int size_col = v2d[0].size();
```