# Finding the size of a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, size

I have a question about finding the size of a 2D vector. My simple question is that I have a vector with which stores three "shapes" each shape has a random number of hitpoints (stored as Cartesian coords {x,y,z}) and each hitpoint has a random color (stored as RGB) I want to find out how many hitpoints each shape has. If I do:

```
VectorOfShapes.size()
```

I get the answer

```
3
```

This is a similar question asked before 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534830/c-size-of-a-2d-vector). But it didnt help me. Their solution was

```
VectorOfShapes[1].size()
```

I tried that and I got the following error "[error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175971/error-c2228-left-of-size-must-have-class-struct-union)
". Which was nicely answered (follow the link). It still doesn't help me (or Im being stupid)...
Any ideas?

//----------Added info

```
class World {
public:
vector<Flux*>   VectorOfShapes;
void
containers(int obnum, Ray reflect, RGBColor Ll);
void                    
build(void);
void
add_vectorshape(Flux* vectorshape_ptr)
private:
void
delete_VectorOfShapes
}
inline void
World::add_vectorshape(Flux* vectorshape_ptr){
VectorOfShapes.push_back(vectorshape_ptr);
}

void
World::containers(int obnum, Ray reflect, RGBColor Ll)
{
vectorOfShapes[obnum]->push(reflect);
VectorOfShapes[obnum]->push(Ll);
int sizers = VectorOfShapes[0].size(); //this is where the code is giving me errors
}

void                                                
World::build(void) {
Flux* vectorshape_ptr1 = new Flux;
add_vectorshape(vectorshape_ptr1);
Flux* vectorshape_ptr2 = new Flux;
add_vectorshape(vectorshape_ptr2);
Flux* vectorshape_ptr3 = new Flux;
add_vectorshape(vectorshape_ptr3);
}

void
World::delete_VectorOfShapes(void) {
int num_VectorOfShapes = VectorOfShapes.size();

for (int j = 0; j < num_VectorOfShapes; j++) {
    delete VectorOfShapes[j];
    VectorOfShapes[j] = NULL;
}   

VectorOfShapes.erase (VectorOfShapes.begin(), VectorOfShapes.end());
}

    class Flux{

public:
std::vector<Ray> rays;
std::vector<RGBColor>    L;


void push(Ray ray); 
void push(RGBColor Ls) ;   


};
inline  void 
Flux::push(Ray ray) { 
rays.push_back(ray); 
}

inline void 
Flux::push(RGBColor Ls){ 
L.push_back(Ls); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post declaration of `VectorOfShapes` ?

Comment: In `VectorOfShapes[1].size` , `.size` is probably a method, not a variable, so you need to call it like `VectorOfShapes[1].size()`. But it's hard to tell without nothing what is `VectorOfShapes`.

Comment: `float HitPoints = VectorOfShapes[0].x + VectorOfShapes[0].y + VectorOfShapes[0].z`?

Comment: Sorry @karlphilllip typo, i corrected it

Comment: Are the vector elements pointers?

Comment: @hmjd no they are not pointers

Comment: You need to post the declaration of `fluxs`.

Comment: The "added info" is useless...

Comment: Sorry, do you mean vector<Flux*> fluxs;

Comment: Even with the updated question, I still can't find the declaration of `VectorOfShapes`.

Comment: @karlphillip, I suspect that `fluxs` is the `VectorOfShapes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment providing the declaration of `fluxs`:

```
vector<Flux*> fluxs;
```

`fluxs` is a vector of pointers, meaning:

```
fluxs[i]
```

returns a `Flux*`, not a `Flux` so you must use `->`, as you have done in the posted code for setting attributes. Without the definition of `Flux` I am assuming there is a getter for obtaining the `hitpoints` and as stated there are exactly three elements in `fluxs`, so to get the total of hitpoints in `fluxs` you could just:

```
int total_hitpoints = fluxs[0]->get_hitpoints() +
                      fluxs[1]->get_hitpoints() +
                      fluxs[2]->get_hitpoints();
```

EDIT:

If the *hitpoint* count is the number of elements in `Flux::rays` (or `Flux::L`) then:

```
int total_hitpoints = fluxs[0]->rays.size() +
                      fluxs[1]->rays.size() +
                      fluxs[2]->rays.size();
```